# Append different object into list but the list result in same objects repeating

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Im trying to create a function that return all the neighboring node of a state of n-queens on the chess board, and below is my code, mainly is to generate a list of neighboring node based on the parameter input state.

```
#Generate neighboring state's function
def generate_neighbor_node (cur_state):
    current = cur_state
    neighbor = current
    neighbor_list = []
    for i in range(qs):
        chg_value = neighbor[i]
        chg_value +=1
        if chg_value == qs:
            chg_value =0
        neighbor[i] = chg_value 
        print neighbor       
        neighbor_list.append(neighbor)
    #Reverse the process, to change the node value back to original for next
    #loop to generate another valid neighbor state
        chg_value -=1
        if chg_value == -1:
           chg_value = (qs-1)
        neighbor[i] = chg_value    

   return neighbor_list                

print board
ai = generate_neighbor_node(board)
print ai

The output is like this:
1. [1, 3, 2, 0]
2. [2, 3, 2, 0]
3. [1, 0, 2, 0]
4. [1, 3, 3, 0]
5. [1, 3, 2, 1]
[[1, 3, 2, 0], [1, 3, 2, 0], [1, 3, 2, 0], [1, 3, 2, 0]]
```

But what I really want is the list to contain is the array 2,3,4 and 5 but not 1
How to do it? Please help, thanks.

Comment: What does the output mean? Can you explain the algorithm you are using?

Comment: the output is generated when i run the program, it seems that if i print 1 by 1 the neighbor node inside the loop, it is what i want, but when i append into the list and print it out, its not the result that i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you call `neighbor_list.append(neighbor)` you just add a reference to `neighbor`, rather than a new list. This means that every list in `neighbor_list` is just the current value of `neighbor`.

To fix this, you should make a copy of the list like this:

`neighbor_list.append(copy.copy(neighbor)`

[Documentation for copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)